# How to check for the presence of a session variable in Mule MEL?

Tags: variables, mule, mule-studio, mel

I need to check if a session variable exists.  I can check if it is present and set to a variable:

```
<when expression="#[sessionVars['foo'] == 'true']">
```

But I want something like:

```
<when expression="#[sessionVars['foo']]">
-- or --
<when expression="#[Exists(sessionVars['foo'])]">
```

Since, sometimes 'foo' is not assigned a variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing for nullity should do the trick:

```
<when expression="#[sessionVars['foo'] == null]">
```

Or, as suggested by Anton below:

```
<when expression="#[sessionVars.containsKey('foo')]">
```

Comment: Also sessionVars.containsKey('foo')

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the session variable exist `request_id = #[sessionVars.ses_request_id]`

when you type `request_id = #[sessionVars.ses_re]` it will automatically shows the mule expression.